# Add web references to Windows service

Tags: windows-services

I'm going to add web references to a windows service.

But whatever I have done was not useful.

Is there any special way to add web references to windows service?
I'm a beginner when it comes to Windows services.

Any help will be appreciated

Regards,

Comment: i have seen[http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/asp-net-web-services/2706/Adding-web-reference-to-a-windows-service]useful link

Comment: nothing but when i start to install the service the service does not install complete

Answer (score 0):

First of all: make sure your service works (without the web service reference) - it needs to install and start up properly.

Then I would add some logging - does it run? Where does it run to? Catch all exceptions that might happen and log those, too.

You might also want to check out some "hybrid" approaches, that would allow you to write your code as a command-line app first (which can be easily debugged), and once it works okay, you can then install it as a service:

- [HybridService: Easily Switch Between Console Application and Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HybridService.aspx)
- [Hybrid Windows Service](http://hws.codeplex.com/)
- [TopShelf - a service-construction helper for .NET](http://topshelf-project.com/)